# Does a namespace-scope constructor definition require a class-qualified identifier?

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor

Here's something we all learned on Day 1 of C++, which we take for granted but doesn't clearly follow from the wording of the Standard.

Given a class `S`, we can define its constructor

```
struct S { S(); };
S::S() { … }
```

But the Standard seems to allow this just as well:

```
struct S { S(); };
S() { … }
```

Qualifying the name of a class with itself is always allowed but always redundant. For example `S::S::S::S() { … }` is also a valid declaration. If `S::S` is, why not plain `S`?

From C++11 §12.1/1,

> Constructors do not have names. A special declarator syntax is used to declare or define the constructor. The syntax uses:
>
> — an optional decl-specifier-seq in which each decl-specifier is either a function-specifier or constexpr,
>
> — the constructor’s class name, and
>
> — a parameter list
>
> in that order.

This applies equally to class or namespace scope. There is a special rule about namespace scope, §9.3/5,

> If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class definition, the member function name shall be qualified by its class name using the :: operator.

However, *constructors do not have names*, so this doesn't apply, right? Moreover, there's no reason to require the qualification, because there is no syntactic ambiguity. A function declared with no return type and a class-name for an identifier is always a syntax error under currently observed rules. Right?

Not that we should start writing code with the qualification omitted, but is there a reason that no compiler accepts this, or is it just tradition?

Comment: You sire, have a wicked mind. I am interested in the discussion that's going to ensue.

Comment: Who gave this a -1?? And WHY?

Comment: @Nim: I think someone doesn't like what I might do to their beloved language. Unfortunately, now my rep score will be 2 off from a multiple of 5 until I can accept an answer to this question.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, you could always go around and down vote three times! ;)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Based on your quotations I think you could equally say that since a constructor *is* a member function (even though it doesn't have a name), and since its member function name cannot possibly be qualified (since it doesn't have a name), therefore *constructors may not be defined lexically outside their class definition*! Except that, the text about `class-name::class-name` quoted by Eric Z is another special-case syntax for constructors, and that is what permits `S::S()` but not plain `S()` in namespace scope.

Comment: @Steve: 9.3/5 doesn't seem to imply that there must be a member function name, just that such a name must be qualified. The notation `C::C` denotes the constructor *in a primary expression*, but that doesn't seem to relate to 12.1/1… or have any effect or use at all.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: oh, OK, it's just not allowed then if we take a strict interpretation of that sentence. It says "the name shall be qualified", not "if there is a name, then the name shall be qualified". No name, no satisfaction of that requirement. "Passengers shall show their ID" means no ID, no travel, it doesn't mean "if you have ID you must show it, if you don't have one then welcome aboard". I think that interpretation is just as valid as your interpretation that `S()` is allowed, and of course neither of them is how implementers or the committee interpret the text.

Comment: @Steve: "Passengers shall show their ID" does not state what happens if no ID exists. It's left quite open-ended. The authorities can rightly conclude that they can deny passage to anyone not showing an ID, but that is another rule hopefully written elsewhere. "The member name shall be qualified…" does not imply that if something else takes the place of a member name, it must be qualified instead. The question here is what qualifying the class-name with itself accomplishes.

Comment: In general, a logical implication is satisfied if its requirements ("antecedents," looking up my vocabulary on Wikipedia) are not met. There are only two ways to extrapolate 9.3/5. One is "… and if there is a member function name, it shall be qualified…", and the other is "… and there shall be a member function name, which shall be qualified…" The first option seems more reasonable to me and imposes no requirements on a constructor, and the second can't be satisfied for a constructor in any case as you've noted.

Comment: How's `S::S::S` legal? Since `S::S` unambiguously names the ctor (§ 3.4.3.1/2), `S::S` is not a scope in which you can look up S again.

Comment: @MSalters: Interesting. So `S::S` is special and `S::S::S` is invalid, but 3.4.3.1 doesn't seem to require that `S::S` be used to name the constructor in a namespace scope declaration, as opposed to plain `S`. (For what it's worth, Comeau and GCC accept any number of nested `S::S`'es.)

Comment: @MSalters: Ah, C++11 3.4.3/1 says "If a :: scope resolution operator in a nested-name-specifier is not preceded by a decltype-specifier, lookup of the name preceding that :: considers only namespaces, types, and templates whose specializations are types." The constructor being none of these things, it is not an "acceptable lookup result" so 3.4.3.1/2 doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When faced with the tokens `S() { }` at namespace scope, the compiler can't magically decide it's a ctor. Which grammar rule would produce such a sequence of tokens? Let's ignore everything but function-definitions; they can't produce the `( ){ }` part.

That means that `S()` must be a *declarator* , and the *decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* has to be empty (see §8.4.1). §9.2/7 subsequently tells us that the *declarator* must name a constructor, destructor, or conversion function. But `S` doesn't name either. Therefore, `S() { }` is invalid.

Comment: 9.2/7 says "The decl-specifier-seq may be omitted in constructor, destructor, and conversion function declarations only…" It doesn't say anything about what the declarator names, so the implementation should check against 12.1 to see if it's a constructor. This applies equally to class and namespace scope, and `S` is the same class-name in either case.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yes, the compiler has restricted the possible options to those three, it then needs to check which of those it is. Since there's no `~` nor an `operator`, the only possible option indeed is a ctor. Which one? At global scope, `S` doesn't name a ctor but a class.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it says that,

> If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class definition
>     the member function name shall be qualified by its class name using the :: operator.

But it ***doesn't*** says that member function w/o name shall ***not*** be qualified by its class name. Does it? ;)

That seems to lead to an uncertain area depending on implementations. However, the form of A::A is defined by the Standard.

*5.1 Primary Expressions*

> Where class-name :: class-name is used, and the two class-names refer to the same class, this notation names the constructor..

As to whether `A(){..}` is allowed or not, I guess there is no reason to do it conventionally(Is there ANY C++ compiler allow it?? AFAIK, nope):

1. Since constructor is a special member function, the way of `A::A(){..}` is more consistent with other member functions. Why borther allow it to behave specially? That's probably not worth the effort.
2. No one wants to run the risk of writing non-compliant code that's not explicitly stated in the Standard.

Comment: This does not forbid `struct S { S(); }; S() { … }`.

Comment: Also, that only applies to expressions, while the syntax from 12.1/1 takes the place of a declarator. However, I didn't know about that, so now I'm curious, is there any valid expression which names the constructor?

Comment: "But it doesn't says that member function w/o name shall not be qualified by its class name. Does it? ;)" It does say that constructors can be declared and defined without qualification.

Comment: @R.Martinho, could you please quote where it is said?

Comment: @Eric: it's on the question: §12.1/1 "(...) A special declarator syntax is used to declare or define the constructor (...)". The non-optional parts are: the class name, and the parameter list. The constructor "name" is not required.

Comment: @R.Martinho, yup, I see. So that appears to be a matter of convention then ;)

Answer (score 1):

Although this question was ambiguous at best in the originally published C++11 Standard and at the time of this question, [Defect Resolution 1435](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1435) was accepted in April 2013, changing the relevant text so that a constructor definition at namespace scope does require a *qualified-id* (the syntax using `::`) as the "name".

The same paragraph in C++14 (or near that time) was:

> Constructors do not have names. A declaration of a constructor uses a function declarator ([dcl.fct]) of the form
>
> *ptr-declarator* `(` *parameter-declaration-clause* `)` *exception-specification*<sub>*opt*</sub> *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> where the *ptr-declarator* consists solely of an *id-expression*, an optional *attribute-specifier-seq*, and optional surrounding parentheses, and the *id-expression* has one of the following forms:
>
> - in a *member-declaration* that belongs to the *member-specification* of a class but is not a friend declaration ([class.friend]), the *id-expression* is the injected-class-name ([class]) of the immediately-enclosing class;
> - in a *member-declaration* that belongs to the *member-specification* of a class template but is not a friend declaration, the *id-expression* is a *class-name* that names the current instantiation ([temp.dep.type]) of the immediately-enclosing class template; or
> - in a declaration at namespace scope or in a friend declaration, the *id-expression* is a *qualified-id* that names a constructor ([class.qual]).

This paragraph has had a few more minor tweaks, none altering the answer to this question. The [current version](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.ctor#general-1) reads:

> A *declarator* declares a *constructor* if it is a function declarator ([dcl.fct]) of the form
>
> *ptr-declarator* `(` *parameter-declaration-clause* `)` *noexcept-specifier*<sub>*opt*</sub> *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> where the *ptr-declarator* consists solely of an *id-expression*, an optional *attribute-specifier-seq*, and optional surrounding parentheses, and the *id-expression* has one of the following forms:
>
> - in a friend declaration ([class.friend]), the *id-expression* is a *qualified-id* that names a constructor ([class.qual]);
> - otherwise, in a *member-declaration* that belongs to the *member-specification* of a class or class template, the *id-expression* is the injected-class-name ([class.pre]) of the immediately-enclosing entity;
> - otherwise, the *id-expression* is a *qualified-id* whose *unqualified-id* is the injected-class-name of its lookup context.
>
> Constructors do not have names. ...